# Parallax image flies to the left

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform, parallax

I found some problems with parallax, while resizing browser my parallax image flies to the left. I need to have it 50% width with pinned to the right side.

http://jsbin.com/hukafomepi/1/edit?output

Could You help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: well, i'm out. No idea why it would translateX like that. Sorry dawg

Comment: My js knowledge is poor, what I found is translate3d("+e.x+"px, "+e.y+"px, 0)"}else if(m==="csstransforms"){e.transform="translate("+e.x+"px, "+e.y+"px)"} but I don't know how to play with this:)

Comment: well if you wanted to hack the plugin, turn `"+e.x+"` to `"0"` everywhere you see it. That will force the X to stay at 0

Comment: it's not working, image disappeared:/

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve, and what is wrong? I don't understand...

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the plugin to jquery.parallax-scroll and it works now.